Trying to test Driver Manager throwing SQLException using Mockito
The constructor I am testing is here:
    public Query(String sql, Object... parameters) throws SQLException {
        try {
            this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Credential.URL, Credential.USER, Credential.PASSWORD);
            this.preparedQuery = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
                this.preparedQuery.setObject(i + 1, parameters[i]);
            }

            this.results = preparedQuery.executeQuery();
            log.info("Connection established and query executed successfully.");
        } catch (SQLTimeoutException e) {
            log.error("Connection timeout exceeded: {}", e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("Error executing query: {}", e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }

In my Test class I have this test:
    @Test
    public void testConstructorThrowsSQLException() {
        try (MockedStatic mockedDriverManager = mockStatic(DriverManager.class)) {

            mockedDriverManager.when(() -> DriverManager.getConnection(anyString(), anyString(), anyString()))
                .thenThrow(new SQLException("Database connection error"));
        }
    }

The problem I am having is where I say
.thenThrow(new SQLException("Database connection error"));

The new SQLException("Database connection error") is causing Mockito to throw an UnfinishedStubbing exception.
When I change it to .thenThrow(SQLException.class); it works just fine. Does anybody know why this happens?
I am using Mockito version 4.0.0

Here is SQLException constructor you use
    public SQLException(String reason) {
        super(reason);
        this.SQLState = null;
        this.vendorCode = 0;
        if (!(this instanceof SQLWarning)) {
            if (DriverManager.getLogWriter() != null) {
                printStackTrace(DriverManager.getLogWriter());
            }
        }
    }

It calls DriverManager.getLogWriter() and you in process of mocking it.
Solution is
mockedDriverManager.when(() -> DriverManager.getConnection(anyString(), anyString(), anyString()))
    thenAnswer(ignore -> new SQLException("Database connection error"));


Thank you, this works. Why does this work?

Because now constructor called after the mocking is done.
